# Regular expression to stop at first match immediately

Tags: python-3.x, python-re

So this is a given string where you can see in some places there are missing values.
We have to fill those missing values in a certain specified way.

```
s = "_, _, 30, _, _, _, 50, _, _ "
```

My concern for the first bit of the problem is to extract the " _, _, 30 " part from the string ( so that i can take it apart, modify and replace the modifed bit in the original string ). I tried to do it using:

```
import re
res = re.findall("_.*[0-9]",s)
print(res)
```

The output I am getting is:

```
_, _, 30, _, _, _, 50
```

whereas the desired result is:

```
_, _, 30
```

How can i do it using re module?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is coming from the fact, that on default regex operators are greedy - which means they return *the longest* match, there are 2 ways to solve your problem:

(1) Just to move from greedy to non-greedy operator:

```py
>>> re.findall("_.*?[0-9]+",s)
['_, _, 30', '_, _, _, 50']
```

(2) Replace "any" with non-numeric:

```py
>>> re.findall(r"[^0-9]*[0-9]+", s)
['_, _, 30', ', _, _, _, 50']
```

Comment: great!!... But hey is there any way to get only  _, _, 30 as my result ? Also, can you please explain the pattern you used in the second method??

Comment: @crackjack to get only first match - replace `findall` with `search` and add `.group()` at the end e.g. `re.search("_.*?[0-9]+",s).group()`. For the second regex  - it's matching `[^0-9]` - anything that is *not* numeric (i.e. "^" in square brackets is negation of all the following characters), so match non numeric 0+ characters, finished by at least one numeric character (`*` means 0+ characters, `+` means 1+ characters). It's a bit more smooth way of balancing greedy/non-greedy operators (imo).